# Prototype is not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is not working in IE6 but working in all other browsers. The error is propertyType is undefined and the function does not works for IE6.

My function is,

```
function propertyType(){}

propertyType.prototype.contactClear=function()
{
    $('#error_msg').text('');
    $('#error_msg').css("display","none");
    $('#name').val(LANG.LBL_NAME+':');
    $('#email').val(LANG.LBL_EMAIL+':');
    $('#phone').val(LANG.LBL_PHONE+':');
    $('#message').val(LANG.LBL_MESSAGE+': '+LANG.LBL_CONTACT_ME);
    $("#captchaval").val('');
    $("#success_msg").text('');
    $('#success_msg').css("display","none");
}

var propertyType = new propertyType();
```

Can anyone suggest me to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would now be a good time to remind people that IE6 is to old / buggy / crap to care about? :)

Comment: @webnoob IE6 may be a nuisance but sometimes we still need to cater for it. If you are hired by a client who has a large proportion of users using IE6 (often out of a lack of choice) then you should develop for that browser if you are doing your job right. In an ideal world IE6 would have gone, but it hasn't.

Comment: Is that really all your code? And where does the error occur?

Comment: This function relates to clear, when i clear the form the script error occurs as 'propertyType is undefined' in IE6

Comment: @drmonkeyninja - Don't worry I understand, most of the governmental offices within the UK still use it so I know it's still required. Still, the fact we WILL support it means they don't have to stop using it which is bad for the industry. Anyways, not the time or place :)

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur if you are attempting to `clear` or `hide` the elements before they loaded into the `DOM`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: Use `window.onload` function which also can be used to avoid this issue occurence.